# `ImageMultiply`, `ImageSubtract` and `ImageAdd` in "LAB" space

Tags: image-processing

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Okh.png"];

r = ColorCombine[{#, ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1], 
  ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1]}, "RGB"] &@
  ColorSeparate[im, "RGB"][[1]];
g = ColorCombine[{ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1], #, 
  ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1]}, "RGB"] &@
  ColorSeparate[im, "RGB"][[2]];
b = ColorCombine[{ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1], 
  ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1], #}, "RGB"] &@
  ColorSeparate[im, "RGB"][[3]];
Grid[Partition[{r, g, b, ImageMultiply[
  {r, ImageMultiply[{g, b}]}], im}, UpTo@3]]
```

This CMY color separation, when stitched together with `ImageMultiply` gives

[image]

but I have no idea where the red is coming from in the lightness channel here:

```
l = ColorCombine[{#, ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1], 
  ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1]}, "LAB"] &@
  ColorSeparate[im, "LAB"][[1]];
a = ColorCombine[{ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1], #, 
  ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1]}, "LAB"] &@
  ColorSeparate[im, "LAB"][[2]];
b = ColorCombine[{ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1], 
  ColorNegate@Binarize[#, 1], #}, "LAB"] &@
  ColorSeparate[im, "LAB"][[3]];
Grid[Partition[{l, a, b, ImageMultiply[
  {l, ImageMultiply[{a, b}]}], im}, UpTo@3]]
```

[image]

LAB colour space should look like this:

[image]

[source](http://shutha.org/node/851)

but when I use `ImageMultiply[l, ImageMultiply[a, b]]` I get a very darkened version:

[image]

Is this because `ImageMultiply` is performed in RGB space?

Comment: Martin, can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? If you look at ColorSeparate[im], you see the R, the G, and the B channels each represented as a matrix of values and visualized in greyscale. Similarly, if you look at ColorSeparate[im, "LAB"], you see the L, the A and the B channels each represented as a single matrix of values.

Comment: Yes, please explain in plain words what you are trying to do. The code is opaque and contains unusual constructs. I couldn't tell why it doesn't work as I can't even tell what it's meant to do.

Comment: @bill s have updated now, hope it's a bit clearer, though I don't think I have construction right on LAB separation (is inverse of what I want, but still rather stange)

Comment: @Szabolcs have updated now, hope it's a bit clearer

Comment: Could you explain why do you think `ImageMultiply` is needed here? Where in the definition of Lab space does it say you have to multiply the channels together? As I understand it, you have to go through the XYZ colour space conversion to go between Lab and RGB.